# remove() com jquery id com ()

Tags: jquery

No HTML que recebi existem muitas DIVs assim (ou quase assim): nome-do-id-(24498765);

Ao executar isso em jquery:

```
$('#'+'nome-do-id-(24498765)').remove();
```

Recebo o seguinte erro:

```
jquery.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #nome-do-id-(24498765)
```

Percebi que o erro está nos () (partenteses), sei que não é certo criar IDs com (), mas recebi assim o sistema. Como fazer com que o Jquery identifique IDs que tenham parenteses no seu nome?

Comment: nome-do-id é o que realmente está escrito ou é uma representação ? se for uma representação, comenta aqui um modelo real.

Comment: é uma represnetação, pode ser qualquer nome sem caractere especial e acento, mas sempre com parenteses: kudshf-(2333) jdskhf-dsfds-(9), etc... o problema é o parenteses

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver assim:

```
var nomeArquivoApaga = nomeArquivo.replace('(', '\\(');
var nomeArquivoApaga = nomeArquivoApaga.replace(')', '\\)');
```

Comment: Nem precisa utilizar **replace**, vc consegue fazer isso direto no selector `jQuery`!